# Paging fails at 50 items per page when ordered by newest

Tags: bug, status-completed

I have noticed a problem when I try to move through the questions page with the count per page set to 50.  The date on the posts jumps back to the first page of questions for the site even though I'm only about 25% of the way through, and then the next few screens are blank.

It does not exhibit this problem when I go through 15 at a time.

This seems to occur on both Chrome 19 and Firefox 12.

[image]

---

## Bug Features as of 09:11 UTC 28/05/2012:

- 50 per page view sorted by newest is correct up until page 13
- On page 14 only one question is listed and it's very recent (from 2 days ago)
- Pages 15 and 16 are blank
- Page 17 (last page) has the recent question listed again on its own
- Also the question before the bug starts is definitely not the oldest question we have, so it looks like a fair few are being missed out entirely too :/

No repro for other pagination sizes or other sort orders.

Comment: Repro after page 14.  I'll see if it's a problem on other sites

Comment: Tried a few but apparently we're the lucky ones :L  I'll try and get some dev attention :)

Comment: Are you ignoring any tags?

Comment: @CodyGray No ignored tags (no favorited either).

Comment: @RoryM I had tried to reproduce it on CogSci and Chem, but neither has as many pages as Bio does.

Comment: @jonsca It felt good seeing our nice big number :L  I also checked Poker (again too small) but Christianity was large enough and didn't seem to be affected

Comment: @RoryM Seems to be working better today, has anything changed?

Comment: @jonsca *shrug*, gremlins :D